# How to shorten fall time of NPN transistor

Tags: amplifier, bjt

I have built a circuit containing a 2N3904 NPN transistor.  I am using this to amplify a signal to send it longer distances and then drop it back down to 5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxFmZD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While debugging the circuit, I noticed the resulting square wave has a longer fall time than expected.  Below are screenshots of the resulting waveform: red is the original and blue is the result (measured at TX_DATA_5V_AMP).

**Resulting waveforms**

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

- Why is the fall time so much longer than the rise time on this waveform?
- How can I shorten the fall time on this circuit?  Can I shorten it by changing the resistor values or the transistor?

Comment: The answer to this question covers the subject pretty well: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23349/how-do-i-make-the-turn-off-and-turn-on-time-equal-in-a-npn-transistor

Comment: The input is on the emitter?

Comment: @Simus994 Yes, and it is intentional. Q1 is used as a [common base amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever's providing TX_DATA_5V is an open-drain/open-collector output. You'll want to add a pullup resistor, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYQQqa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This resistor will pull the line high when the signal is high, and is necessary because open-drain/open-collector outputs can only drive the signal low. If you want a faster fall time, you can reduce the value of R4. Be careful you don't end up sinking too much current into your microcontroller's output though.